# Laravel container Linking to Docker memcached container

Tags: php, laravel, docker

i try to use docker container to link memcached container,but $serve['port'] get full URL

here for some information

laravel .env

```
MEMCACHED_HOST=memcached
MEMCACHED_PORT=11211
```

docker for laravel project

```
docker run --name DAC -d --link mysql57:mysql -p 8082:80 -v --link memcached:memcached dac
```

docker memcached images use official memcached:latest
https://hub.docker.com/_/memcached

```
docker run --name memcached -d memcached
```

but unfortunately when laravel MemcachedConnector->connect i get the error message

```
/var/www/html/dataAnalysisControl/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Cache/MemcachedConnector.php

    public function connect(array $servers, $connectionId = null, array $options = [], array $credentials = [])
    {
        $memcached = $this->getMemcached(
            $connectionId, $credentials, $options
        );

        if (! $memcached->getServerList()) {

            foreach ($servers as $server) {
                $memcached->addServer(
                    $server['host'], $server['port'], $server['weight']
                );
            }
        }

        return $memcached;
    }

"Memcached::addServer() expects parameter 2 to be int, string given"
```

then i found $server['port'] get not usually

there is i dump the $servers and found this port it should be 11211

but i got tcp://172.17.0.4:11211 so get the string given error

```
array:1 [▼
  0 => array:3 [▼
    "host" => "memcached"
    "port" => "tcp://172.17.0.4:11211"
    "weight" => 100
  ]
]
```

so i try test a original connect

```
$m = new Memcached();
$m->addServer('memcached', 11211);
$version = $m->getVersion();
$m->set('key', 'test');
$get_value = $m->get('key');

dd($version,$get_value)

/////////dump///////
array:1 [▼
  "memcached:11211" => "1.5.19"
]

'test'
```

it look like memcached connect not a problem

so clearly, I am silly miss a step at somewhere here.

I hope someone can help me give me a solution.

Comment: better to post docker-compose, or your linking command.

Comment: `"port" => "tcp://172.17.0.4:11211"` - are you sure about this? Whatever this `port` value should hold, I'd assume it should not hold a full URL including the protocol and host information

Comment: thx,i add command at top @Adiii

Comment: @NicoHaase  yes,i rellay got this full URL from MemcachedConnector->connet ,so i don't know miss what?

Comment: If the `port` value shoud provide a **port**, it should not contain a full URL, shouldn't it?

Comment: you meant the link is not correct so i get full URL?

Comment: Consider using docker compose

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally i find some solution.

1.
first way is use docker-compose, turn out problem resolve, get correct $server['port']  11211.

make sure use same network in yml file

btw: thx @Elias Soares remind me use docker-compose

2.

if MEMCACHED_PORT will change to be full URL like 'tcp:XXX.XXX.XXX:11211'

so i add other config to make sure the service not mess up by container link

edit config>cache.php

```
           'servers' => [
                [
                    'host' => env('MEMCACHED_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
                    'port' => env('**MEMCACHED_CUSTOMER_PORT**', 11211),
                    'weight' => 100,
                ],
            ],
```

then edit .env file write correct port in my case is 11211

tip the port number make sure match you memcached container setting port